# determine radius of convergence of one series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{n^2},$$ 
how can we determine the radius of convergence of this series?

When $x=R$ or $-R$, what can we say?

Comment: Did you mean
$$\Large (\text{A})\;\;x^{2n}\qquad (\text{B})\;\;x^{n^2}\qquad (\text{C})\;\;x^{2^n}$$
or something else entirely?

Comment: $R=1$; at $x=\pm 1$ series diverges. Do you need details?

Comment: need to switch the position between n and 2 above x

Answer (score 1):

Use the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{(n+1)^2}}{(-1)^{n}x^{n^2}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{n^2+2n+1}}{x^{n^2}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|x^{2n+1}\right|$$

so the series only converges for $0\le |x|\lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

Here, $b_n=a_{n^2}=(-1)^n$.

Now find $$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|$$

So, $R=1$

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your series is an alternating series. So all that remains is to find all values of $x$ for which
$$
  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n^2} = 0.
$$
It is easy to show that for all $x \in \left]-1, 1\right[$.

Comment: That is a bad idea, as $x^{n^2}$ is not decreasing for $x < 0$.

Comment: But $|x^{n^2}|$ is decreasing, and that's what you need.

Comment: @Adam You need $|x^{n^2}|$ decreasing as well (which is true).

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test you can find that the series converges if $\left|x\right|<1
 $. Maybe it's useful to said that this series is related to one of the Jacobi theta functions $$\theta_{4}\left(z,x\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n^{2}}e^{2niz}
 $$ because, by simmetry, we can write it as $$\theta_{4}\left(z,x\right)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n^{2}}\cos\left(2nz\right)
 $$ then your series is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n^{2}}=\frac{\theta_{4}\left(0,x\right)+1}{2}.
 $$